# Making An HTML Directory List

Tags: php, database, forms, list, html-lists

I have a form on my site where users can enter links to articles

So far... when a link is submitted, I am able to get that link to post to a destination html page.

However... if another link is submitted, it deletes the first one.

I would like the links to 'stack' and make a list to the destination (directory) page (which is currently an html page).

I don't know how to achieve this. Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I have include a very stripped down version of all three pages....

1.) The Form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>FORM</title>

    <style>
    body{margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;}
    .fieldHeader{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12pt;}
    .articleURL{margin-top:10px; width:700px; height:25px;}
    .btnWrap{margin-top:20px;}
    .postButton{cursor:pointer;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="urlUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="fieldHeader">Enter Article Link:</div>
    <input class="articleURL" id="articleURL" name="articleURL" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="btnWrap"><input class="postButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="POST"></button></div>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. The Upload PHP (buffer) Page

   ```
   <?php ob_start(); ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>urlUpload</title>
   <style>body{margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php $articleURL = htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleURL']); echo  $articleURL;?>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php echo ''; file_put_contents("urlDirectory.html", ob_get_contents()); ?>
   ```

3.) The Destination HTML 'Directory List' page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>urlDirectory</title>

    <style>body{margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px;}</style>

    </head>
    <body>
    Sumbitted URL's should be listed here:
    </body>
    </html>
```

PS: I may not even need the middle php 'buffer' page. My knowledge of this sort of thing is limited thus far. If I don't need that, and can skip that page to accomplish my needs, please advise as well.

Comment: Are you storing these values in a database or do you simply want to add to a list within the html file?

Comment: No sjdaws. Not storing in a database. Just want to use the form submissions to generate the list within the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using PHP to write the file and using `urlDirectory.html` as a template. You will just need to change your php file:

**urlUpload.php**

```
<?php

function saveUrl($url, $template, $tag)
{
    // If template is invalid, return
    if (!file_exists($template)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Remove whitespace from URL
    $url = trim($url);

    // Ignore invalid urls
    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Read template into array
    $html = file($template);

    foreach ($html as &$line) {
        // Look for the tag, we will add our new URL directly before this tag, use
        // preg_match incase the tag is preceded or followed by some other text
        if (preg_match("/(.*)?(" . preg_quote($tag, '/') . ")(.*)?/", $line, $matches)) {
            // Create line for URL
            $urlLine = '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleURL']) . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;

            // Handle lines that just contain body and lines that have text before body
            $line = $matches[1] == $tag ? $urlLine . $matches[1] : $matches[1] . $urlLine . $matches[2];

            // If we have text after body add that too
            if (isset($matches[3])) {
                $line .= $matches[3];
            }

            // Don't process any more lines
            break;
        }
    }

    // Save file
    return file_put_contents($template, implode('', $html));
}

$template = 'urlDirectory.html';

$result = saveUrl($_POST['articleURL'], $template, '</body>');

// Output to browser
echo $result ? file_get_contents($template) : 'Template error';
```

Comment: Thank you sjdaws. I'm a little confused as to where that new php should go?  I started with the 3 diff pages in my question. In your example... how many will your example?

Comment: Apologies, your form is fine, my answer replaces `urlUpload.php` and `urlDirectory.html` respectively.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just confused because the urlUpload file looks the same with now changes.

Comment: Yep the only difference is I removed the placeholder.

Comment: Ok. Fingers crossed, gonna give a shot. I'll report back. Thank you.

Comment: I gave it a shot. unfortunately... no luck. Nothing popped up on the urlResults PHP page, and when I went tot the url directory page, there was a lot of code on the screen.

Comment: I've clarified my answer. If this prints php code when you visit it you might be running it on a server which doesn't support PHP. I've verified it works locally. You can't just run `c:\dir\form.html` in your browser, it needs to be on a http server like apache or nginx.

Comment: WORKS! Thank you so much!

Comment: sjdaws... you still online?

Comment: I’m around, if you want to chat give me 20 mins

Comment: That would be perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146922/discussion-between-sjdaws-and-jamie-sexton).